# The Nash inequality on a compact manifold without a boundary.

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

> Let $M$ be a compact manifold without boundary. Does the Nash inequality
>   $$\lVert u \rVert^{1+\frac 2n}_{L^2} \leq C\lVert u \rVert^{\frac 2n}_{L^1} \lVert \nabla u \rVert_{L^2}$$
>   or something similar hold on $M$?

From what I read in the book by Hebey, "*Poincare's inequality iff Nash's inequality*", but that is old, maybe something better is known now. I can make $M$ as smooth as needed.

Comment: Do you assume that $\int_M u = 0$?

Comment: @John No, I only assume $u$ is in whatever spaces necessary for the inequality to make sense. (eg $u \in H^1(M)$).

Comment: In Poincare inequality, one need to make additional assumption to exclude constant $u$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you asked the question, the answer is obviously negative, take any constant function different from 0. If M is not connected then even zero average is not enough to guarantee the inequality.